# How to use httpclient with elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, post, httpclient

I'm receiving an exception when I try to post a Json in Elasticseach:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). 
in System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() 
in httpclient.Program.<Run>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\httpclient\httpclient\Program.cs:riga 17
```

Could someone help me?

I would like add a document in the index "indexx".
I need to use a task list because I must use async method to avoid a slow down in the app.

Thanks in advance

The code:

```
    public static List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> PostList = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string c = "{\"book\": \"Help me\"}";
        var content = new StringContent(c, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://10.236.0.124:9200/indexx"), content).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PostList.Add(Run());
        try
        {
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(PostList.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("WaitAll() has not thrown exceptions. THIS WAS NOT EXPECTED.");
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe following exceptions have been thrown by WaitAll(): (THIS WAS EXPECTED)");
            for (int j = 0; j < e.InnerExceptions.Count; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n---------------\n{0}", e.InnerExceptions[j].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5000);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.236.0.124:9200");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders
              .Accept
              .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, "indexx");
        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"book\": \"Help me\"}",
                                            Encoding.UTF8,
                                            "application/json");

        await client.SendAsync(request)
              .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result);
              });
    }
```

Comment: You aren't speeding anything up with async here. But the bigger problem is your "Bad Request". You need to check what you are sending against what the documentation says you need to send.

Comment: Is there any additional information in the response to say why it failed? Maybe in the Content or the ReasonPhrase properties?

Comment: Crowcoder -> I have tryed to post the same with the Chrome's plugin "JaSON" and it works fine. 
Simply Ged -> There is no additional information in the response..

Comment: For one the index API needs a type specified, so try adding /typename to the end of the URL

Comment: sramalingam24 -> I have tried to add the type (http://10.236.0.124:9200/indexx/typee) but it doesn't work.

Comment: If I use curl and run this command:
    curl -XPOST "http://10.236.0.124:9200/indexx/typee" -d "{\"book\": \"Help me\"}"
It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your request with this and it worked with elastic.co . 
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "yourindexname/_doc/" );